# Android get filesize after take camera?

Tags: android, camera

How can i get file size after take camera.
I run the code the following results:filesize is 0.I think that the Camera InputStream is writing.But how can I get the real file size?

```
private void takeCamera(){
    file = File.createTempFile("tp_", ".jpg", dir);
    filePathCamera = file.getAbsolutePath();
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
                final File file = new File(filePathCamera);
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    result.append("not exists\n");
                    return;
                }
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                try {
                    inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePathCamera);
                    long size = inputStream.available();
                    result.append("size1:" + size + "\n");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (inputStream != null) {
                            inputStream.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                        // ignore
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `onActivityResult` in `case REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:` after checking if `!file.exists()` you can check in else part file.length which will give you size of file.

Comment: i have try `available()` and `length()` but not work.